# How to initialize a 3d array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array:

```
char array[4][4][2];
```

What i want is a table 4x4, that allocate a string of two characters on each position. But, when i initialize the array like that:

```
char array[4][4][2] = {{"AA", "BB","  ", "  "}, {"CC", "DD", "  ", "  "}, {"EE","FF","  ","  "}};
```

And make:

```
printf("%s\n", array[0][0]);
```

The output is:

```
AABB    CCDD    EEFF
```

So, what's the right order to do that? I didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: strings in C have char* type. char is for one symbol e.g. 'C'

Comment: You forget the null terminal char. Make it `char array[4][4][3]` Since the memory is contiguous. It explain why you have the concatenation of all string.

Comment: @mathk - and he's lucky that he only initialized three of the four elements, so that there is a `'\0'` in the uninitialized part of the array to terminate the string...

Comment: @leonardo because question is tagged to C but not C++ So I like to comment: this is correct declaration in C but this special case is only C; it gives you an array that doesn't contain a null-terminated string. C++ doesn't have that special case, and a C++ compiler should reject it. So better is keep practice to leave last dimension declare it as  `char array[4][4][] = {{"AA", "BB",....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string in C requires a terminator, `'\0'`. So a 2-character array is too small for a string with two visible characters.

It's a feature of C's string array initialization that you don't get a warning or error for doing what you do; as often in C it's assumed that you know what you're doing.

If you do:

```
char foo[] = "foo";
```

you will get a four-character array with a terminator appended automatically, but if you do

```
char bar[3] = "bar";
```

you won't get a terminator since it doesn't fit, but you will not get an error either.

To fix it, increase the third size to `[3]` to make room for the terminator.

Many programmers would probably implement this instead as a 2D array of character pointers, but that uses a lot more memory than your design. It does buy you simplicity though:

```
const char *array[2][2] = { { "AA", "BB" }, { "CC", "DD" } };
```

This will make the compiler put the actual character data, with terminator characters added, *somewhere* in memory, and `array` will simply be a 2x2 array of pointers to the proper locations for the start of each string.

Comment: Interesting, another difference between C and C++; C++ will produce an error if you try to cut off the null terminator like that.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it is correct initialization of `char` array. but you can't use `%s` as your array is not NUL (`\0`) terminated. According to your declaration you can write:

```
printf("%c%c\n", array[0][0][0], array[0][0][1]);
```

Or correct array dimension so that it accommodates a string of length 2, followed by the `'\0'` terminator character:

```
char array[4][4][3] = { {"AA", "BB", "  ", "  "}, 
/*               ^  */  {"CC", "DD", "  ", "  "}, 
                        {"EE", "FF", "  ", "  "}
                      };
```

Comment: I think you should also add that "last dimension is 3 because 2 array cell is for two chars and 1 cell is for NUL"...:)

Comment: @haccks that is what I mean to say "correct array dimension so that two length string accommodate" I point out correction. ....improve it  I will be thankful, and correct my spelling mistakes also. Thanks!

Comment: @haccks your edits are helpful for me, I learn that where I make mistakes it help me to improve.

Comment: No dude...Actually I am learning from your answers. This is because you are always trying to do best. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
int ii, jj;
const char *array[2][2] = {{"hello", "world"},{"these are", "strings"}};
for (ii=0; ii<2; ii++) {
  for (jj=0; jj<2; jj++) {
    printf("%s\n", array[ii][jj]);
  }
}
```

This shows you how to properly allocate a 2D array of strings - you don't determine the size of each string, it is determined by the initialization. The compiler will make sure they are null terminated and everything - and they don't even need to be all the same size.

Note - what I actually did was create a 2D array of pointers, rather than a 3D array of characters. This is more flexible, and more appropriate to your case, since you appear to be interested in strings (which are arrays of characters, but are referenced by pointing to their start; and as @unwind pointed out, they need to be null terminated).

Comment: ...and by doing this you can save some memory. +1.

Comment: @haccks - when the strings are of different length, this will probably save memory over a "make enough space for the longest string" approach. If all are the same size (and not null), storing the characters only is a bit more efficient - especially on 64 bit systems where each pointer occupies 8 bytes... But I definitely think this is cleaner.

Comment: Actually I did't mention in my comment, I am talking about `arrays of pointers`.